# How to add environment variable permanently in ~/.bashrc file in Macbook pro?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

After installing Confluent Kafka I have set the environment variable by exporting command below:

export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/confluent/bin
export CONFLUENT_HOME=/opt/confluent

Also, I modify the ~/.bashrc file with lines above.

But everytime i close the Terminal window it doesn't recognize kafka command until I re-export those line again.

Is there any way i can permanently set those variable?

Comment: In Terminal, execute `echo $SHELL`. What is the output?

Comment: echo $SHELL returns /bin/zsh

Comment: Starting with macOS Catalina, the [default shell is zsh](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050). You need to modify the `~/.zshrc` file  instead.